# Откуда берется русская локализация в сборке telegram, если соответствующих файлов нет в ресурсах?

Tags: android, telegram

Осуществляю сборку telegram для android:
https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram
и хотя в ресурсах отсутствует русский язык, в приложении все же появляется кнопка "Продолжить на русском" после нажатия, которой 
интерфейс становится локализованным.
Собственно я выяснил, что русской локализации в исходниках нет, когда вознамерился добавить в нее одну строку.
Буду очень благодарен за пояснение, возможно локализация каким-то образом присутствует, а я просто не могу её обнаружить...

Comment: Посмотрите последнюю секцию в ридми внутри репозитория.

Comment: @D-sideЯ смотрю, там ссылка, видимо,  на сервис для коллективной локализации, однако, мне как-то все-равно не очевидно, что происходит в итоге. Он из сети получает локализацию, но почему тогда другие языки представлены, как и положено, в файлах строковых ресурсовв, и кроме того,  в папке сборки на компьютере я нахожу файл "values-ru.xml" со всеми переводами сообщений, который непонятно откуда там берется.

Comment: Скачивается с этого сервиса, по всей видимости.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед авторизацией приложение качает файл русской локализации и предлагает "Продолжить на русском". Файл лежит по пути

> /data/user/0/org.telegram.messenger/files/remote_ru.xml

Далее есть класс `LocaleController` который разворачивает файл в `HashMap`. Все обращения к ресурсам приложения выглядят так:

```
LocaleController.getString("FloodWait", R.string.FloodWait);
```

Например тут строка "FloodWait" передается как раз в метод `getString`, используется там как ключ для `HashMap` и метод возврашает русский вариант перевода. А вот и он, кстати (файл remote_ru.xml):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]